# Alternative proof by Induction

Tags: summation, induction, alternative-proof

I have to prove by induction, for  $n\ge 1$ , this equality:

\begin{gather}\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \frac{i(i+1)}{8}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2} \end{gather}

For it, i use \begin{gather}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \end{gather}

My question is: there is a way to prove the first equality by Induction , without the use of the second equality, as i have done? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a typo or just $n^3$?

Comment: You probably mean $i^2$ as opposed to $n^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\frac{(2n-1)2n}8+\frac{2n(2n+1)}8=\frac n4\bigl((2n-1)+(2n+1)\bigr)=n^2.$$

Comment: Thank you! I found my mistake thanks your hint.  Thanks again!